# git log for a portion of a file

Tags: git

I would like to see all the git commits that affected what are currently lines x - y in one of my files.  Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: Why do want to do that ?

Comment: I have some code that doesn't make any sense.  I want to see how it ended up in its current state.  There have been a lot of commits to this file and most of them don't touch the lines in question.  I don't want to look through the 500 commits to find the 4 that matter.

Comment: This is an interesting question, and I was going to ask it myself, but I realised that there is no sensible way to define "line" in the context. In the context of file browsing/editing, a line is defined by it's line number. But as soon as a file has n lines added to it, then every line after that becomes line x+n, and your log is out of whack. There may be a smart way of following lines back through the history, but it'd be pretty computationally intensive, I would think.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Now `git log` supports the `-L` option like `git blame`.  This was added in Git v1.8.4.

```
 -L <start>,<end>:<file>
 -L :<regex>:<file>

 Trace the evolution of the line range given by "<start>,<end>" (or
 the funcname regex <regex>) within the <file>. You may not give any
 pathspec limiters. This is currently limited to a walk starting from a
 single revision, i.e., you may only give zero or one positive revision
 arguments. You can specify this option more than once.
```

([git-log documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log))

Answer (score 5):

You can use `git blame` with the -L option:

```
-L <start>,<end> 

 Annotate only the given line range. <start> and <end> can take one of these forms: 

 number 

If <start> or <end> is a number, it specifies an absolute line number (lines count from 1).

 /regex/ 

This form will use the first line matching the given POSIX regex. If <end> is a regex, it will search starting at the line given by <start>.

 +offset or -offset 

This is only valid for <end> and will specify a number of lines before or after the line given by <start>.
```

So it will be something like below:

```
git blame -L 40,60 foobar
```

Note that git blame shows the latest revision for each line. You can also try with the `--reverse` option:

> --reverse
>
> Walk history forward instead of
>   backward. Instead of showing the
>   revision in which a line appeared,
>   this shows the last revision in which
>   a line has existed. This requires a
>   range of revision like START..END
>   where the path to blame exists in
>   START.

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-blame.html

You can probably also use

```
gitk foobar
```

Comment: This only shows the one change though.. I think we're looking for something like git-log but for a certain line range.

Answer (score 0):

Not really the answer to your question, but you might use `git blame <file>` and ask the person that wrote the lines that bother you.